# Check one checkbox when other is selected

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make one checkbox select when the other one is selected. This is what I have come up with:

```
    <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function(){

                                    var chk1 = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='notify']");
                                    var chk2 = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='notify_comments']");

                                    chk1.on('change', function() {
                                        chk2.prop('checked', this.checked);
                                    }
                                    });
                                </script>

<input type="checkbox" name="notify">
<input type="checkbox" name="notify_comments">
```

Comment: What does `tep_draw_selection_field()` do?

Comment: You need to put the jQuery code inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @barmar sorry added for clarity

Comment: @Barmar added it and still not working but woops..

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML instead of the PHP that creates it?

Comment: You have syntax errors in your Javascript. See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/xL5b7t5n/2/ for the correct syntax.